# setbeameruncovered problem/bug?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am trying to create a presentation in Beamer using two columns, one column a tikzpicture the other a list. I wish to uncover nodes in the tikzpicture at the same time as a relevant text explanation in the list column. I can do it using `\setbeameruncovered{transparent}` but the greys out the next node and text to be displayed.  I wish to not have the next node/text partially visible. If I use `\setbeameruncovered{}` or comment it out altogether I get the tikzpicture incrementally appearing but the text incrementally disappearing...

Anyone point out the simple error I am making?

Code below...just comment out the `\setbeameruncover{transparent}` to get the disappearing text. (I know it's not the shortest example...!)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Stability of Oxidation States - Ebsworth/Oxidation State Diagrams}

\begin{columns}[t]

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{exampleblock}{Oxidation State Diagram for Manganese}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, every plot/.style={mark=ball, ball color=blue, mark size=5pt}]
\draw[step=0.5cm,gray,very thin] (-0.1,-3.4) grid (7.4,6.4);
\draw[->] (-.5,0) -- (7.5,0)node[near end,below=0.2cm]{\tiny{Oxidation state}};
\draw[->] (0,-3.5) -- (0,6.5)node[rotate=90,midway,above=0.2cm]{$\frac{\Delta G^{\circ}}{F}$};
\foreach \x in {0cm,1cm,2cm,3cm,4cm,5cm,6cm,7cm}
\draw[thick] (\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt);
\foreach \y in {-3cm,-2cm,-1cm,0cm,1cm,2cm,3cm,4cm,5cm,6cm}
\draw[thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
\draw (1,0) node[below]{\tiny{+1}};
\draw (2,0) node[below]{\tiny{+2}};
\draw (3,0) node[below]{\tiny{+3}};
\draw (4,0) node[below]{\tiny{+4}};
\draw (5,0) node[below]{\tiny{+5}};
\draw (6,0) node[below]{\tiny{+6}};
\draw (7,0) node[below]{\tiny{+7}};
\draw (0,-3) node[left]{\tiny{-3}};
\draw (0,-2) node[left]{\tiny{-2}};
\draw (0,-1) node[left]{\tiny{-1}};
\draw (0,0) node[left]{\tiny{0}};
\draw (0,1) node[left]{\tiny{+1}};
\draw (0,2) node[left]{\tiny{+2}};
\draw (0,3) node[left]{\tiny{+3}};
\draw (0,4) node[left]{\tiny{+4}};
\draw (0,5) node[left]{\tiny{+5}};
\draw (0,6) node[left]{\tiny{+6}};

\onslide<2->\draw plot coordinates {(0,0)};
\onslide<3->\draw (0,0) -- (2, -2.36);
\onslide<3->\draw plot coordinates {(2,-2.36)};
\onslide<4->\draw (2, -2.36) -- (3,-0.86);
\onslide<4->\draw plot coordinates {(3,-0.86)};
\onslide<5->\draw (3, -0.86) -- (4, 0.09) ;
\onslide<5->\draw plot coordinates {(4, 0.09)};
\onslide<6->\draw (4, 0.09) -- (6, 4.27) ;
\onslide<6->\draw plot coordinates {(6,4.27)};
\onslide<7->\draw (6, 4.27) -- (7, 5.17) ;
\onslide<7->\draw plot coordinates {(7, 5.17)};

\onslide<8->\draw[thick,color=red] (2,-2.36) circle (0.25cm);
\onslide<8->\draw[thick,color=red,->] (4,-2) -- (2.25,-2.5) node[near start,above right,color=red]{\tiny{Most Stable}};
\onslide<9->\draw[thick,color=red] (7,5.17) circle (0.25cm);
\onslide<9->\draw[thick,color=red,->] (5,5.5) -- (6.75,5.25) node[near start, left,color=red]{\tiny{Most Oxidising}};
\onslide<10->\draw[thick,color=red] (0,0) circle (0.25cm);
\onslide<10->\draw[thick,color=red,->] (1.5,1.5) -- (0.25,0.25) node[near start,above right,color=red]{\tiny{Most reducing}};
\onslide<11->\draw(5,4)  node[left,color=red]{\tiny{Disproportioning}};
\onslide<11->\draw[thick,color=red,->](5,4)--(5.7,4.27);
\onslide<12->\draw[thick,color=red](6,4.27) -- (7,5.17);
\onslide<12->\draw[thick,color=red](6,4.27) -- (4,0.09);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\onslide<1->\begin{exampleblock}{Calculation of $\frac{\Delta G}{nF}$}
  \tiny
  \begin{tabular}{l|rrrr}
      Transition & $n$   & $E^0/V$ & $-nE^0/V$ & $\Sigma$ \\\hline
\onslide<2-> $\onslide<2->0$   &\onslide<2-> 0     &\onslide<2-> 0.00  &\onslide<2-> 0.00  &\onslide<2-> 0.00 \\
\onslide<3->$0\rightarrow 2$ &\onslide<3-> 2     &\onslide<3-> 1.18  &\onslide<3-> -2.36 &\onslide<3-> -2.36 \\
\onslide<4->$2\rightarrow 3$ & \onslide<4->1     &\onslide<4-> -1.50 &\onslide<4-> 1.50  &\onslide<4-> -0.86 \\
\onslide<5->$3\rightarrow 4$ & \onslide<5->1     &\onslide<5-> -0.95 & \onslide<5->0.95  &\onslide<5-> 0.09 \\
\onslide<6->$4\rightarrow 6$ & \onslide<6->2     & \onslide<6->-2.09 &\onslide<6-> 4.18  & \onslide<6->4.27 \\
\onslide<7->$6\rightarrow 7$ & \onslide<7->1     &\onslide<7-> -0.90 &\onslide<7-> 0.90  & \onslide<7->5.17 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{exampleblock}



\onslide<1->{\begin{alertblock}{Stability}
\onslide<8->{\begin{enumerate}
\tiny
\onslide<8->\item The most stable state will have the lowest energy on the oxidation state diagram
\onslide<9->\item Any species located with high $\Delta G$ at high oxidation number will be a strong oxidising agent
\onslide<10->\item Any species located at low oxidation number and high $\Delta G$ will be a reducing agent
\onslide<11->\item Any species located on a convex section can undergo disproportionation
\end{enumerate}}
\end{alertblock}}
\end{column}  
\end{columns}  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just before someone points it out it should be `\setbeamercovered` not `\setbeameruncovered` as I originally wrote in question but not in the code...

Comment: BTW: The [`times`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/times) package you use is obsolete (see [`l2tabu-english.pdf`, section 2.3.1](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf#subsubsection.2.3.1)). You should use either [`mathptmx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx) or [`txfonts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/txfonts) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since `transparent` doesn't, in general, give invisible items, use `invisible` for `\setbeamercovered` (which, by the way is the default so you can simply delete the line for `\setbeamercovered`).
2. Enclose the argument for `\onslide` using braces (I did so in your example code for most of the `\onslide`s but not for all of them (no time to do so)):

Here's your modified code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Stability of Oxidation States - Ebsworth/Oxidation State Diagrams}

\begin{columns}[t]

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{exampleblock}{Oxidation State Diagram for Manganese}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, every plot/.style={mark=ball, ball color=blue, mark size=5pt}]
\draw[step=0.5cm,gray,very thin] (-0.1,-3.4) grid (7.4,6.4);
\draw[->] (-.5,0) -- (7.5,0)node[near end,below=0.2cm]{\tiny{Oxidation state}};
\draw[->] (0,-3.5) -- (0,6.5)node[rotate=90,midway,above=0.2cm]{$\frac{\Delta G^{\circ}}{F}$};
\foreach \x in {0cm,1cm,2cm,3cm,4cm,5cm,6cm,7cm}
\draw[thick] (\x,-2pt) -- (\x,2pt);
\foreach \y in {-3cm,-2cm,-1cm,0cm,1cm,2cm,3cm,4cm,5cm,6cm}
\draw[thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
\draw (1,0) node[below]{\tiny{+1}};
\draw (2,0) node[below]{\tiny{+2}};
\draw (3,0) node[below]{\tiny{+3}};
\draw (4,0) node[below]{\tiny{+4}};
\draw (5,0) node[below]{\tiny{+5}};
\draw (6,0) node[below]{\tiny{+6}};
\draw (7,0) node[below]{\tiny{+7}};
\draw (0,-3) node[left]{\tiny{-3}};
\draw (0,-2) node[left]{\tiny{-2}};
\draw (0,-1) node[left]{\tiny{-1}};
\draw (0,0) node[left]{\tiny{0}};
\draw (0,1) node[left]{\tiny{+1}};
\draw (0,2) node[left]{\tiny{+2}};
\draw (0,3) node[left]{\tiny{+3}};
\draw (0,4) node[left]{\tiny{+4}};
\draw (0,5) node[left]{\tiny{+5}};
\draw (0,6) node[left]{\tiny{+6}};

\onslide<2->{\draw plot coordinates {(0,0)};}
\onslide<3->{\draw (0,0) -- (2, -2.36);}
\onslide<3->{\draw plot coordinates {(2,-2.36)};}
\onslide<4->{\draw (2, -2.36) -- (3,-0.86);}
\onslide<4->{\draw plot coordinates {(3,-0.86)};}
\onslide<5->{\draw (3, -0.86) -- (4, 0.09) ;}
\onslide<5->{\draw plot coordinates {(4, 0.09)};}
\onslide<6->{\draw (4, 0.09) -- (6, 4.27) ;}
\onslide<6->{\draw plot coordinates {(6,4.27)};}
\onslide<7->{\draw (6, 4.27) -- (7, 5.17) ;}
\onslide<7->{\draw plot coordinates {(7, 5.17)};}

\onslide<8->{\draw[thick,color=red] (2,-2.36) circle (0.25cm);}
\onslide<8->{\draw[thick,color=red,->] (4,-2) -- (2.25,-2.5) node[near start,above right,color=red]{\tiny{Most Stable}};}
\onslide<9->{\draw[thick,color=red] (7,5.17) circle (0.25cm);}
\onslide<9->{\draw[thick,color=red,->] (5,5.5) -- (6.75,5.25) node[near start, left,color=red]{\tiny{Most Oxidising}};}
\onslide<10->{\draw[thick,color=red] (0,0) circle (0.25cm);}
\onslide<10->{\draw[thick,color=red,->] (1.5,1.5) -- (0.25,0.25) node[near start,above right,color=red]{\tiny{Most reducing}};}
\onslide<11->{\draw(5,4)  node[left,color=red]{\tiny{Disproportioning}};}
\onslide<11->{\draw[thick,color=red,->](5,4)--(5.7,4.27);}
\onslide<12->{\draw[thick,color=red](6,4.27) -- (7,5.17);}
\onslide<12->{\draw[thick,color=red](6,4.27) -- (4,0.09);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\onslide<1->\begin{exampleblock}{Calculation of $\frac{\Delta G}{nF}$}
  \tiny
  \begin{tabular}{l|rrrr}
      Transition & $n$   & $E^0/V$ & $-nE^0/V$ & $\Sigma$ \\\hline
\onslide<2->$\onslide<2->0$   &\onslide<2-> 0     &\onslide<2-> 0.00  &\onslide<2-> 0.00  &\onslide<2-> 0.00 \\
\onslide<3->$0\rightarrow 2$ &\onslide<3-> 2     &\onslide<3-> 1.18  &\onslide<3-> -2.36 &\onslide<3-> -2.36 \\
\onslide<4->$2\rightarrow 3$ & \onslide<4->1     &\onslide<4-> -1.50 &\onslide<4-> 1.50  &\onslide<4-> -0.86 \\
\onslide<5->$3\rightarrow 4$ & \onslide<5->1     &\onslide<5-> -0.95 & \onslide<5->0.95  &\onslide<5-> 0.09 \\
\onslide<6->$4\rightarrow 6$ & \onslide<6->2     & \onslide<6->-2.09 &\onslide<6-> 4.18  & \onslide<6->4.27 \\
\onslide<7->$6\rightarrow 7$ & \onslide<7->1     &\onslide<7-> -0.90 &\onslide<7-> 0.90  & \onslide<7->5.17 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{exampleblock}



\onslide<1->{\begin{alertblock}{Stability}
\onslide<8->{\begin{enumerate}
\tiny
\onslide<8->\item The most stable state will have the lowest energy on the oxidation state diagram
\onslide<9->\item Any species located with high $\Delta G$ at high oxidation number will be a strong oxidising agent
\onslide<10->\item Any species located at low oxidation number and high $\Delta G$ will be a reducing agent
\onslide<11->\item Any species located on a convex section can undergo disproportionation
\end{enumerate}}
\end{alertblock}}
\end{column}  
\end{columns}  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image showing the first two slides:

[image]

Comment: much appreciated, works a treat. I knew it would be something simple!