# Put a figure with a table side by side

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a table and a figure, I want to align them one next to the other (not one under the other):

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[t]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth }
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{ | c || c | c | c | c | } \hline
\textbf{ABC} & \textbf{KO} & \textbf{Ro} & \textbf{Ov} & \textbf{Params} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Well this is a text here}} \\ \hline
\textit{A1} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\textit{Z2} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Well this is another text here)}} \\ \hline
\textit{O1} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\textit{U9} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{results in this table}
\label{validation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{plot.pdf}
\caption{This is a figure not a table}
\label{plot}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions?rq=1

Comment: In `beamer` there is the `columns` environment which allows you to do this. I'm not sure if this environment is available outside of `beamer`.

Comment: @Leeser nope. But there´s something more reliable. See my answer below.

Comment: @bloodworks The figure and its caption are overlapping with the table, with your solution

Comment: @bloodworks "nope" as in there isn't a comparable environment outside of `beamer`?

Comment: @Leeser i dont get the sense of your last comment. When you need to divide a page into several smaler pages the default way to do that would be to use `minimage` (as shown below) unless you need your content to spread over many pages (then you may use `multicol` or some other two or more column layout facilities)

Comment: @bloodworks I didn't understand what you meant by "nope". What were you saying nope to? "Nope" that there isn't a `columns` environment in `beamer` (which there is) or "nope" that the `columns` environment isn't available outside of `beamer`, which is quite possible. Or "Nope" that I'm completely wrong on all accounts! Just a clarification on what the answer "nope" was referring to. I'm not arguing that your solution is wrong. A solution in `beamer` where there is a picture in one column and table is given in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50506/setbeameruncovered-problem-bug

Comment: @Leeser ok i´m sorry we ran into a communication clash right here. I just intended to say that there is no `beamer`like `columns` environment  outside `beamer`. Nothing personal.

Comment: @bloodworks. No worries, I didn't take anything personal, so no need to apologise. It is hard to convey tone and meaning in a few short characters and it can come across quite different to what was meant. I hope you didn't think I was getting worked up ...as it appears ...now that I re-read my 2nd reply...!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) you could do the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[t]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth }
        \footnotesize
        \begin{tabular}{ | c || c | c | c | c | } \hline
            &\\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{the caption of table}
        \label{thelabeltab}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{myimage.pdf}
        \captionof{figure}{my caption goes here}
        \label{thelab}
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When using a KOMAScript Class `capt-of`is not needed. If the Example doesn´t help you i suggest that you provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

***Update:***
 Here comes a extended example with some (debuging) frames to show you the placement of the two objects. (When you compare this example with the one above you`ll easily figure out which commands to strip to get rid of those lines.)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{capt-of, showframe, blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{table}[t]\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[b]{.50\textwidth }%
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{ | c || c | c | c | c | } \hline
\textbf{ABC} & \textbf{KO} & \textbf{Ro} & \textbf{Ov} & \textbf{Params} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Well this is a text here}} \\ \hline
\textit{A1} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\textit{Z2} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Well this is another text here)}} \\ \hline
\textit{O1} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\textit{U9} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{results in this table}\label{validation}%
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}%
\hspace*{0pt}\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{plot.pdf}%
\captionof{figure}{This is a figure not a table\label{x}}%
\end{minipage}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With this, I get that the figure and its caption is overlapping with the table !

Comment: @user995434 absolutely not: see the edit. Remember this is all you gave us. Thats why i asked you for a MWE.

Comment: I have edited my first post to put a code with a table and figure as you said, but they are not aligned perfectly ! and the figure is called Table 2 instead of Fig 1 ...

Comment: @user995434: You didn't use the `\captionof{figure}`, and your tabular is simply to large and so sticks out of the minipage.

Comment: using the "llncs" class instead of "book" will not make the captions aligned together !

Comment: Well there is no such class on ctan. What i found using google seems to be a class redefining `minipage` which is crude in my eyes. Maybe you could address the maintainer of this class. BTW that piece of code i found says, that it is __experimental__. Using something which calls itself __experimental__  is not always a good idea.

Comment: I'm not allowed to modify the llncs style which is required for the paper that I'm writing.

Comment: @user995434 are you allowed to load new packages?

Comment: @bloodworks I think yes, if this does not change the style (margin etc)