# aligning a table with a figure side to side using llncs format

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, minipage, lncs

using the `\documentclass{llncs}` instead of for example `\documentclass{book}` will not make the captions aligned together for the following example. How can I do to align them together:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{capt-of, showframe, blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{table}[t]\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[b]{.50\textwidth }%
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{ | c || c | c | c | c | } \hline
\textbf{ABC} & \textbf{KO} & \textbf{Ro} & \textbf{Ov} & \textbf{Params} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Well this is a text here}} \\ \hline
\textit{A1} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\textit{Z2} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Well this is another text here)}} \\ \hline
\textit{O1} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\textit{U9} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{results in this table}\label{validation}%
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}%
\hspace*{0pt}\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{plot.pdf}%
\captionof{figure}{This is a figure not a table\label{x}}%
\end{minipage}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Table captions should generally be placed above tables, as discussed here: [why-should-a-table-caption-be-placed-above-the-table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/why-should-a-table-caption-be-placed-above-the-table). This question seems pretty similar to [your other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62282/put-a-figure-with-a-table-side-by-side)

Comment: @cmhughes for which I didn't get "the" answer.

Answer (score 4):

You may add an invisible anchor at the end of the minipages:

```
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{minipage}[b]{.50\textwidth }%
\footnotesize\centering

\begin{tabular}{ | c || c | c | c | c | } \hline
\textbf{ABC} & \textbf{KO} & \textbf{Ro} & \textbf{Ov} & \textbf{Params} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Well this is a text here}} \\ \hline
\textit{A1} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\textit{Z2} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Well this is another text here)}} \\ \hline
\textit{O1} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\textit{U9} & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\medskip

\caption{\strut results in this table}\label{validation}
\hrule height 0pt
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{plot.pdf}

\captionof{figure}{\strut This is a figure not a table\label{x}}

\hrule height 0pt
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

The `\strut` is used to ensure equal height and depth to the captions.

[image]