# Table right of TikZ image

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, floats, horizontal-alignment

I created a tree using TikZ and would like to add tabular explanation data to the right of it.

The figure definition currently looks like this:

```
\begin{figure*}[h!]
  \input{tikz/praefixeigenschaft}
  \label{f:praefixeigenschaft}
\end{figure*}
```

...and renders to the following tree:

[image: tree]

The explanation text is defined as follows:

```
\begin{tabular}{l l}
  A = 100 & p = 0.2 \\
  B = 1101 & p = 0.1 \\
  C = 1100 & p = 0.1 \\
  D = 111 & p = 0.2 \\
  E = 0 & p = 0.4 \\
\end{tabular}

CEBA: 1100 / 0 / 1101 / 100
```

...and renders to:

[image: text]

I tried both placing the figure in a table and floating the figure using the wrapfig package, but both attempts were not fruitful.

How can I add the explanation text to the right of the figure (like in simple HTML table layout)?

Comment: Hi Danilo. It is always preferable to post complete [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) rather than code snippets because this helps people to answer you.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino thanks, I'll do that next time! :)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62282/put-a-figure-with-a-table-side-by-side or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't give a caption to the figure and try to fix it at the position in text with the `[!h]` parameter, you maybe won't need the `figure` environment at all. You could consider my example code below, where I replaced your figure with some text as you don't give the source code of it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}%
The image
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
  A = 100 & p = 0.2 \\
  B = 1101 & p = 0.1 \\
  C = 1100 & p = 0.1 \\
  D = 111 & p = 0.2 \\
  E = 0 & p = 0.4 \\
\end{tabular}

CEBA: 1100 / 0 / 1101 / 100
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

This renders as follows:

[image]

Comment: `[!h]` doesn't fix the position of the `figure`, it can still float.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems to work using the standalone documentclass, but not inside the normal scrartcl class. Is there a way to fix this, or do I have to include the standalone file in the main document?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. right, I should have written "try to fix it".

Comment: @DaniloBargen Benedikt's code works fine in `scrartcl` as well, so there is something else that's wrong.

Comment: @DaniloBargen What exactly does not work? Do you get errors or warnings? Does it render correctly? If you get an ``overfull box`` warning you have to add a ``%`` sign right after the first ``\end{minipage}``. I will edit my post to take this into account.

Comment: @BenediktBauer oh, i just realized whitespace matters... at first it didn't align side-by-side. thanks, your example works now.

Comment: Looks great now, thanks all for your help! :) http://tmp.dbrgn.ch/screenshots/20121230_151437.png