# Right bigg bracket

Tags: tables, math-mode, amsmath, brackets, makecell

How can I do the right bracket like that of the left hand side?

[image]

Comment: You should provide some code that goes with your question, a minimal working example).  A solution for your problem (supposing wou have the equations in the image) is to introduce TikZ images that do nothing but create nodes at certain places in the equations, and then joint those places.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316068/how-to-define-a-point-for-connecting-nodes-from-two-different-tikz-pictures, the answer with >=4 votes.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that you're interested in typesetting not just a tall curly brace or two, but also some of the other stuff that's shown in the screenshot you posted.

If that's the case, do look into using a `Bmatrix*` environment, which is provided by the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package, a superset of the `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for 'Bmatrix*' environment

\begin{document}
\begingroup % limit scope of the next instruction
\centering
\hrule % draw a horizontal rule across the width of the text block
$\begin{Bmatrix*}[l]  % 'l': left-aligned contents
(123)(45),(123)(45),(123)(45),(123)(45),(123)(45),\\
(123)(45),(123)(45),(123)(45),(123)(45),(123)(45),\\
(123)(45),(123)(45),(123)(45),(123)(45),(123)(45),\\
(123)(45),(123)(45),(123)(45),(123)(45),(123)(45)\\
\end{Bmatrix*}$
\hrule
$\begin{Bmatrix*}[l]
(123),(123),(123),(123),(123),\\
(123),(123),(123),(123),(123),\\
(123),(123),(123),(123),(123),\\
(123),(123),(123),(123),(123)\\
\end{Bmatrix*}$
\hrule
\endgroup % end of scope of '\centering' instruction

\smallskip\noindent
Hello World. % optional
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up query: Here's how I would fix the code the OP posted in a comment to (a) make it compilable without errors and (b) create full-height curly braces. Observe the use of `\left\{` and `\right\}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell,adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\text' macro
\begin{document} 

\begin{adjustbox}{width = 1\textwidth} 
%\large % why??
% use 'array', not 'tabular', environment:
$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 
\hline 
(2,1,1) := 1^1 2^2 & 
(1,2) & 
\left\{    % full-height left-hand curly brace
\text{\makecell[l]{% % process contents of \makecell in text mode
(2 4)(3 5), (1 2)(3 4), (1 5)(3 4), (1 4)(2 5), (1 5)(2 3), \\ 
(1 2)(4 5), (1 3)(2 5), (1 3)(2 4), (1 4)(3 5), (1 2)(3 5), \\ 
(2 5)(3 4), (1 5)(2 4), (1 4)(2 3), (1 3)(4 5), (2 3)(4 5)  }} 
\right\} & % full-height right-hand curly brace
15 \\ 
\hline 
\end{array}$ 
\end{adjustbox} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I use this inside the makecell package? Because initially I used the makecell command to give line break. If yes, how?

Comment: @Memristor - The answer would be "yes". I must admit to having no idea as why one would use `\makecell` to "create line break". Actually, I have no idea as to what you're trying to do, other than to create a tall closing curly brace. Please either edit your posting or, better still, ask a new question, to demonstrate how you employ `\makecell` and inquire whether there might be better ways to accomplish your typesetting objectives.

Comment: This is what i did, sir.   
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document} 
\begin{adjustbox}{width = 1 \textwidth}
\large 
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
\hline $(2,1, 1)$:= $1^1 2^2$ & $(1, 2)$ & \bigg{\{ \makecell{(2 4)(3 5),(1 2)(3 4), (1 5)(3 4), (1 4)(2 5),(1 5)(2 3), \\ (1 2)(4 5), (1 3)(2 5), (1 3)(2 4), (1 4)(35), (1 2)(3 5), \\ (2 5)(3 4), (1 5)(2 4), (1 4)(2 3), (1 3)(4 5), (2 3)(4 5)} } \bigg \}$ & &15$\\ 
\hline

\end{adjustbox}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

Comment: @Memristor - Please see the addendum I posted at  the end of my answer.

Comment:  thank you so much, sir. It works perfectly fine now. Thanks for always coming to my survival.

Comment: @Memristor - Your're most welcome. If you feel that this answer has fully addressed the issue you were looking to fix, feel free to "accept" it by clicking on the green checkmark symbol that's located to the left. ;-)