# Help!! I don't know why the right bigg bracket is not encapsulating everything while the left worked

Tags: tables, brackets, adjustbox, makecell, adjustwidth

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openany, oneside, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document} 
\begin{adjustbox}{width = 1 \textwidth}
\large 
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
\hline $(2,1, 1)$:= $1^1 2^2$ & $(1, 2)$ & \bigg{\{ \makecell{(2 4)(3 5),(1 2)(3 4), (1 5)(3 4), (1 4)(2 5),(1 5)(2 3), \\ (1 2)(4 5), (1 3)(2 5), (1 3)(2 4), (1 4)(35), (1 2)(3 5), \\ (2 5)(3 4), (1 5)(2 4), (1 4)(2 3), (1 3)(4 5), (2 3)(4 5)} } \bigg \}$ & &15$\\ 
\hline

\end{adjustbox}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a full example starting with `\documentclass` and te packages to be used. Maybe `\left`  / `\right` before the `\bbig` will help.

Comment: Did you try to generate a pdf from the given code, if not please try first and fix the problems reported.

Comment: In your previous question it was suggested to use bmatrix, why not using it here?

Comment: Does the addendum to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668886/5001) help?

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is an interesting case.

The main problem is that you're using a wrong syntax that *seems* to produce what you want, but does so just by chance.

How does `\bigg` work? It looks for an argument and does

```
\left<argument><high empty box>\right.
```

(simplified, but the important bits are there); the (empty) `<high empty box>` has a height that should ensure that `\left` finds the desired size. So in your case you get

```
\left\{\makecell{...}\right.
```

and this is ***not*** the intended output.

The correct syntax is

```
\bigg\{ <formula>
```

and indeed, if you remove the wrong braces, you get

[image]

What you want is `\left\{` and `\right\}`.

Here's your table (after fixing a couple of inconsistencies) and my proposal at the bottom.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openany, oneside, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{makecell,adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{width = 1 \textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
\hline
$(2,1, 1)$:= $1^1 2^2$ & $(1, 2)$ &
  $\left\{\makecell{
    (2 4)(3 5), (1 2)(3 4), (1 5)(3 4), (1 4)(2 5), (1 5)(2 3), \\
    (1 2)(4 5), (1 3)(2 5), (1 3)(2 4), (1 4)(3 5), (1 2)(3 5), \\
    (2 5)(3 4), (1 5)(2 4), (1 4)(2 3), (1 3)(4 5), (2 3)(4 5)
  }\right\}$ & $15$\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}


\[
\addtolength{\arraycolsep}{-2pt}
\begin{array}{@{} c|c|c|c @{}}
\hline
(2,1, 1):= 1^1 2^2 & (1, 2) &
\left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
  (24)(35), (12)(34), (15)(34), (14)(25), (15)(23),\\
  (12)(45), (13)(25), (13)(24), (14)(35), (12)(35),\\
  (25)(34), (15)(24), (14)(23), (13)(45), (23)(45)\hphantom{,}
  \end{array}
\right\} & 15 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Avoid `adjustbox`, if possible.

[image]

Comment: I think that a major issue with the OP's code -- other than the fact that it doesn't compile due to several syntax errors... -- is that what's wanted is not `\biggl\{ ... \biggr\}` but, rather, `\left\{ ... \right\}`. See also the addendum to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668886/5001).

Comment: @Mico Indeed! It was a curious byproduct of a syntax error! Fixed.

Comment: +1. :-) You may want to also mention that if the spaces between `2` and `4`, `3` and `5`, etc should be preserved, it's possible to address this need by enclosing the `\makecell{...}` object in a `\textup{...}` directive.