# Horizontally and vertically align tikzpicture includegraphics and text

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a document as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,footskip=2cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces this image

[image: output]

I would like to horizontally and vertically align the three images on the page. I would also like to add some text above and below each image.

**Note** I must use tikzpicture as I am using the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333026/positioning-a-tikz-callout-box-relative-to-image). 
 An example of my desired out put is as below (done roughly in paint)

[image]

Comment: The content is too wide for the page, as LaTeX tells you. And why are you using Ti*k*Z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands, the content is simply too wide for the text block. It is probably easiest to set the scaling as a proportion of the block width.

Ti*k*Z is not needed or especially suitable here. You probably want to handle these as sub-figures of an overall `figure`. The `subcaption` package can help with this.

For example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,footskip=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{Some text above the whole figure.}
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{First, an exciting contribution by unknown artist.}
  \end{subfigure}\quad
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Second, an anonymous mystery.}
  \end{subfigure}\quad
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Finally, an inscrutable offering by artist unknown.}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Exhibition by Three Anonymous Artists]

If the text above isn't meant to be a caption, just use regular text. If you need to refer to the figures or sub-figures, just use `\label{fig:whatever}` after the relevant `\caption`(s).

## EDIT

If you really need then to be in `tikzpicture` environments, that's fine. Just nest them inside the `subfigure`s. You just need to alter the size of the images included, obviously, to make room.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,footskip=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{Some text above the whole figure.}
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node {\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{First, an exciting contribution by unknown artist.}
  \end{subfigure}\quad
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node {\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Second, an anonymous mystery.}
  \end{subfigure}\quad
  \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node {\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Finally, an inscrutable offering by artist unknown.}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Enhanced Exhibition by Unknown Artists]

Comment: Hi @cfr. Thanks for your answer. I should have stated that I do have to use tikz, as I am using this solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333026/positioning-a-tikz-callout-box-relative-to-image to have callout boxes automatically resize depending on my scaling.

Comment: The point is, you don't need Ti*k*Z for *this*. You can put the `tikzpicture`s in the `subfigure`s with the images inside nodes inside the pictures. But for labelling them, you still want captions and you still want them to be sub-figures if you want separate captions.

Comment: @SteveHatcher Please see edit above.