# How to draw arrows from tables inside a node to another node

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I'm trying to draw specific arrows from table cells to nodes. This is what I have done so far:

[image]

I'm trying to get this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth,node distance=4cm,semithick]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw=black,text=black,minimum size=2cm]

  \node[state]at (0,0)(0)  {
                    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
                    \hline
                    \rowcolor{gray!50}
                     5   \\\hline
                     13  \\\hline
                     14  \\\hline
                    \end{tabular}
                   };
  \node[state]at (-4,-4)(1)  {
                    \begin{tabular}{|c|  }
                    \hline
                     \cellcolor{gray!50} 1   \\\hline
                     11  \\\hline
                     12  \\\hline
                    \end{tabular}
                   };

  \node[state](2)  at (-2,-8){
                    \begin{tabular}{|c|  }
                    \hline
                     \cellcolor{gray!50} 2   \\\hline
                     17  \\\hline
                     18  \\\hline
                    \end{tabular}
                   };;
  \node[state](3) at (4,-4) {
                    \begin{tabular}{|c|  }
                    \hline
                     \cellcolor{gray!50} 3   \\\hline
                     15  \\\hline
                     16  \\\hline
                    \end{tabular}
                   };
  \node[fill=gray!50,state](4)  at (6,-8)   {4 jump };
  %\node[fill=gray!50,draw=black,text=black,minimum size=2cm](6)  at (6,-8) { };
   \node[draw=black,thick,circle,inner sep=4.5pt](6)  at (6,-8)   {4 jump };
  \node[state](5)   at (-6,0)     {
                    \begin{tabular}{|c|  }
                    \hline
                     \cellcolor{gray!50} 5   \\\hline
                     17  \\\hline
                     18  \\\hline
                    \end{tabular}
                   };

\draw (0) -- (1);
\draw (0) -- (3);  

\draw (1) -- (3);
\draw (1) -- (2);

\draw (2) -- (4);
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=4pt,yshift=2pt}] (2)--(1);

\draw (3) -- (2);
\draw (3) -- (4);

\draw (5) -- (1);
\draw (5) -- (3);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please forgive me, but to me, your result looks much smoother and more elegant, than the second image.  I think, you don't need the "bumps" at the crossing lines, as you have arrows at the end.  Unless you **really need to** connect a particular cell in the table, there is neither a need, to elongate the lines into the circles.  Its just my two cents, but I'd stay with that neat and clean result, you have achieved.  It is very appealing to me!

Comment: I completely agree!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to get the arrows to start from the cells not the the node.

Comment: I have no time to try now, but if you use a native tikz`matrix` instead of the circular nodes with tabulars inside you can address the individual cells easily. You can then draw a circle around them if you really want... otherwise, you can use `tikzmark` http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/295987/38080

Comment: Another method could be to write the Contents of the cells next to the arrow, this way you could Show, which value is used. But then again i don't know what you want to Show.

Comment: I tried using tikzmark but it didn't work with tikzpucture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with `multipart` shapes instead of tables:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                automata, 
                calc, 
                fit,                % <-- added
                shapes.multipart,   % <-- added
                tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth, semithick,
 node distance = 4cm, 
  state/.style = {shape=rectangle split, draw,
                  rectangle split parts=3,
                  rectangle split part fill={gray!30,white},
                  minimum width=20mm},
fitnode/.style = {shape=circle, draw, inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt,
                  node contents={}}                    
                        ]
\node (0) [state]               {                   5   \\
                                \nodepart{two}      13  \\
                                \nodepart{three}    14  
                                };
\node (10) [fitnode, fit=(0)];
\node (1) [state] at (-4,-4)    {                   1   \\ 
                                \nodepart{two}      11  \\
                                \nodepart{three}    12  
                                };
\node (11) [fitnode,fit=(1)];
\node (2) [state] at (-2,-8)    {                   2   \\ 
                                \nodepart{two}      17  \\
                                \nodepart{three}    18  
                                };
\node (12) [fitnode,fit=(2)];
\node (3) [state] at (4,-4)    {                    3   \\ 
                                \nodepart{two}      15  \\
                                \nodepart{three}    16  
                                };
\node (13) [fitnode,fit=(3)];
\node (4) [shape=circle,draw, fill=gray!50, 
           double=gray!50,double distance=2mm, 
           align=center,
           inner sep=3mm,outer sep=1.5mm] at (4,-8)   {4\\ jump};
\node (5) [state] at (-6,0)    {                    5   \\ 
                                \nodepart{two}      17  \\
                                \nodepart{three}    18  
                                };
\node (15) [fitnode,fit=(5)];
%
\draw   (0.west)  edge (11) 
        (0.east)  edge (13) 
        (1.east)  edge (13) 
        (1.south) edge (12) 
        (2) edge (4) 
        (2.three west) edge [out=180,in=270] (11.south)
        (3.south) edge (12)
        (3.east)  edge [out=0,in=0] (4)
        (5.south) edge (11)
        (5.east)   --  (13);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
considering  *Guilherme Zanotelli* comments and some further improvements of existing code, where is exploited `positioning` TikZ library for relative positioning of nodes controlled by `node distance` and redefined `state` style. For simplified relative positioning of nodes they are renamed. With this measures code become far more concise:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                automata, 
                calc, 
                fit,                % <-- added
                positioning,        % <-- added
                shapes.multipart,   % <-- added
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[semithick,
     node distance = 24mm and 12mm, 
 state/.style args = {#1 #2 #3}%
        {shape=rectangle split, draw,
         rectangle split parts=3,
         rectangle split part fill={gray!30,white},
         minimum width=17mm,
         node contents={\nodepart{one}  #1  % <-- added                 
                        \nodepart{two}  #2        
                        \nodepart{three}#3},
         append after command=\pgfextra{   % <-- added
            \node (1\tikzlastnode) [fitnode, fit=(\tikzlastnode)];}%%
         },
   jump/.style = % <-- added
        {shape=circle,draw, fill=gray!50,
         double=gray!50,double distance=2mm,
         align=center,
         inner sep=3mm, outer sep=1.5mm
         },        
fitnode/.style = 
        {shape=circle, draw, 
         inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt,
         node contents={}}                    
                        ]
\node (1)  [state=5 17 18];
\node (2)  [state=1 11 12,below right=of 1];
\node (3)  [state=5 13 14,above right=of 2];
\node (4)  [state=3 15 16,below right=of 3];
\node (5)  [state=2 17 18,below right=of 2];
\node (6)  [jump,right=of 5] {4\\ jump};
%
\draw[-stealth]
    (1.south)  edge (12)
    (1.east)   edge (14)
    (2.east)   edge (14)
    (2.south)  edge (15)
    (3.west)   edge (12)
    (3.east)   edge (14)
    (4.south)  edge (15)
    (4.east)   edge [out=0,in=0] (6)
    (5.east)   edge (6)
    (5.west)    to  [out=180,in=270] (12);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you use `append after command={\pgfextra{\node (1\tikzlastnode) [fitnode, fit=(\tikzlastnode)];}}` inside the `state` style there will be no need for all the `\node (yx) [fitnode, fit=(x)];`

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli, thank you for the tip. However, using this  the it is not possible to manage connection between "tables" (multi part nodes) and circles around them. This is one of OP demands, as far I understand question.

Comment: Of course it is! with `\pgfextra{\node (1\tikzlastnode) [fitnode, fit=(\tikzlastnode)];}` we are creating a new node which received the name of the previously delcared node plus a `1`, exactly as you do manually. If you do as I say and remove all the `\node (1x) [fitnode, fit=(x)];` your code still compiles perfectly! `:)`

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli, with your help I significantly improve answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: Indeed, much more Ti*k*Zxy! And better than using `\matrix`, the code is now **neat**! `:D`

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Jan, the drawing you made Looks much better. But that's for you to judge, we're here to help only. `:)`

So, this seems like a `matrix` thing. A `\matrix` in tikz is a big node that contains other nodes inside, the beauty of it is the automatic naming. Say you name a matrix `A` by using: `\matrix (A) {...};` all nodes inside the matrix `A` will have names like `A-<row>-<column>`. And since the matrix itself is a node, you can use `anchor, above, inner sep` and so on.

Finally, the nodes iside the `\matrix` are defined like if they were a table, so your syntax needs little modification, only removing the `\begin \end{tabular}` and the `\hline`s would suffice. Let's get to the MWE!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth,
    node distance=4cm,semithick,
    every state/.style={
        draw=black,
        text=black,
        minimum size=2cm},
    row 1/.style={fill=gray!50},
    state matrix/.style={
        state,
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=0pt,
        column sep=0pt,
        nodes={draw, rectangle, minimum height=0pt, minimum width=3em}}]
  \matrix[state matrix] (0) at (0,0)  {
                     |[row 1]| 5\\
                     13\\
                     14\\};
  \matrix[state matrix] (1) at (-4,-4) {
                     |[row 1]| 1   \\
                     11  \\
                     12  \\};

  \matrix[state matrix] (2) at (-2,-8){
                     |[row 1]| 2   \\
                     17  \\
                     18  \\};

  \matrix[state matrix] (3) at (4,-4) {
                     |[row 1]| 3   \\
                     15  \\
                     16  \\};
  \node[state,fill=gray!50,double=gray!50, double distance=5pt] (4)  at (6,-8) {4 jump };
  \matrix[state matrix] (5) at (-6,0) {
                     |[row 1]| 5   \\
                     17  \\
                     18  \\
                   };
\foreach \i in {0,...,5} \node[above] at (\i.north) {\i};
\draw[->]%
    (5-2-1.east) edge (3)
    (5-3-1.south) edge (1)
    (0-2-1.west) edge (1)
    (0-2-1.east) edge (3)
    (1-2-1.east) edge (3)
    (1-3-1.east) edge (2)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `matrix` library makes available the `matrix of nodes` style, which reduces the amount of `\node` necessary (check the manual for further info), with that style all nodes inside the Matrix receive the style provided by `nodes={sty keys}`, so I gave them all a `minimum width=3em` but you can adjust that value. Furthermore I used `double` in the `4 jump` node instead of drawing it twice with different sizes. I drew some of the edges but left the rest to you as I now am out of time! Also there's a `\foreach` naming the state matrices just for a reference to draw the edges, just remove it once you're done.

For the lines jumping one another check [Intersection of 2 lines not really connected in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111660/intersection-of-2-lines-not-really-connected-in-tikz) Mark Wibrow has a pretty neat answer there and I made a slight modification of it (which is also answered there).

[image]

Comment: @user123348, you're welcome! And, I forgot to add this: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, it's not even in the manual anymore. To define a style one should use the handler: `mystyle/.style={keys}` which work inside pretty much anywhere a style can be applied.