# How to make this floating textbox in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am doing an assignment for my college and I need help making this colored box on the side[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [todonotes - How to add todo notes? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9796/how-to-add-todo-notes) should cover most of the answer. For the rest you find an appropriate background color, line width etc.

Comment: Maybe also this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295903/refer-to-a-node-in-tikz-that-will-be-defined-in-the-future-two-passes could help.