# How to use tikz package to produce margin notes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, marginnote

I want to produce margin notes like this

[image]

[image]

But they should behave like `\marginnote` command. The reason I want this is the flexibility of `tikz` package when I want to modify how the content should appear (e.g., boxes, backgrounds, alignment, transparency, anchors, etc)

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\geometry{twoside=true, showframe=true}
\geometry{inner=5mm, outer=5mm, includemp=true, marginparsep=3.5mm, marginparwidth=61mm}

% END_FOLD

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{bigstrut}

\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}

\usepackage{marginnote}


\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, remember picture, overlay]
    
    \node[text width=61mm, align=flush left, inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=1pt, outer xsep=0pt, outer ysep=0pt, anchor=north east] at (current page marginpar area.north east) {\bigstrut \blindtext};
    
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\smash{\rlap{\rule{\dimexpr \linewidth + \marginparsep + \marginparwidth \relax}{0.1pt}}}%
\blindtext
    
\newpage

\noindent%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, remember picture, overlay]
    
    \node[text width=61mm, align=flush left, inner xsep=0pt, inner ysep=1pt, outer xsep=0pt, outer ysep=0pt, anchor=north east] at (current page marginpar area.north east) {\bigstrut \blindtext};
    
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\smash{\rlap{\hspace*{\dimexpr - \marginparsep - \marginparwidth \relax}\rule{\dimexpr \linewidth + \marginparsep + \marginparwidth \relax}{0.1pt}}}%
\blindtext

\newpage

\marginnote{\blindtext}%
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you checked the `todonotes` package? If I remember correctly, it is built upon tikz and it allows a lot of customization.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295903/refer-to-a-node-in-tikz-that-will-be-defined-in-the-future-two-passes can suggest a possible starting point